# Error 1069 the service did not start due to a logon failure

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-service

Our CruiseControl.NET service on Win2003 Server (VMWare Virtual) was recently changed from a service account to a user account to allow for a new part of our build process to work.

The new user has "Log on as a service" rights, verified by checking Local Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment, and the user password is set to never expire.

The problem I'm facing is every time the service is restarted, I get the 1069 error as described in this questions subject. I have to go into the properties of the service (log on tab) and re-enter the password, even though it hasn't changed, and the user already has the appropriate rights.

Once I enter the password apply the changes, a prompt appears telling me that the user has been granted log on as a service rights.  The service will then start will no problems.

Not a show stopper, but a pain none-the-less.  Why isn't the password persisting with the service?

Comment: I am seeing this exact same behavior on our W2k3 Server using our service account. Once the credentials are reentered the Tomcat service can then be restarted. I did recently move the Tomcat installation folder to one that contains no spaces. I'm anxiously waiting for a solution to your question.

Comment: The only thing our sysadmin found was that "the local admin group doesn't have specific local security privileges necessary to start the service, the local Administrator does and the Domain Admin group does but not other local administrators." Our user is not the 'Administrator' account but does have admin rights, so is in the local admin group.

Comment: I have had a similar problem on a client server. Turns out the software application that the service account is for uses a specific port, hard coded. Another application on the same server is using the same port, and is hard coded also. I suspect that if both applicaitons send traffoc over the same port, the password ofthe service gets corrupted.

Comment: I had the very same issue. As it turned out: There have been 2 GPO Settings, both modifying the "Log on as a Service" Entry. It seems like the later GPO applied always wins, therefore removing the first Setting.

Answer (score 3):

When you enter the password manually, the user is added to the 'Log on as service' list. I think you have group policy on the network which is overwriting this user list. After it overwrites you will have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

The error means the password is incorrect. Does the Application when installed have any other references to any other (older) account?

Comment: I appreciate it's an authentication error, but re-entry of the (same) password starts the service, so for some reason Windows isn't remembering the password.  The applications service has no references to the service account it was previously run under.